# How to import text file in excel using java?

Tags: java, excel, import

is it possible to import text file in excel with Java?

i have a text file with some value, years...etc
If i want to import this text file, i have to open excel and then import it.
but i want to do it with java

any help
thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create both XLS and XLSX files in plain Java using [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) library. It also allows you to read Excel files.

Of course you can also format your text files as CSV and let MS Excel open it - most of the time it should work.